# Realtime Video Processing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, video-processing

We have a requirement to 'read' an LED Pulse lamp using the iPhone video camera. The LED lamp emits the light based on some load conditions.

Is there any related iPhone API to help achieve this goal?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [AVFoundation framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) to read and process the live video stream from the camera. WWDC 2010 Session 405 gives you a good overview of AVFoundation.

Comment: Combine that with e.g. OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

There are iOS AV APIs to get raw pixel bitmaps from the video camera(s).  Detecting any specific image or brightness within these raw bitmaps has to be done in your own code.